# How to display Pin's Label (on a Map) without clicking on it Xamarin.Forms pcl

Tags: c#-4.0, xamarin.forms

```
var pin = new Pin
{
    Type = PinType.Place,
    Position = new Position(currentlat, currentlong),
    Label = "My Current Location ",
    Address = "My Current Location "
};
map.Pins.Add(pin);
```

Here when i click on pin i can see the label address. But i want to see label on pin without Clicking on it..

Comment: Any solution regarding this ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use property of Map.SelectedPin property.

Just set Map.SelectedPin = Pins[i];

This will show a label on your pin without clicking on it.

Comment: Map doesn't have a `SelectedPin` property in Xamarin Forms.

Comment: @Eric Erhardt Map has Selected pin property, I have used it in my project. 
 <maps:Map x:Name="MapView"
                          SelectedPin=""
                          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

This is the code I have used to select the pin. 
Please check  if you are using latest xamarin forms package.

Comment: are you talking about https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps/ ?  I (and I think the OP) was talking about https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Maps